# Parse a CSS file to to get individual declarations of selectors containing a right or left word

Tags: ruby, regex

I need to parse a CSS file to to get individual selectors that contain a right or left word in their declarations(block). And add the selectors and their corresponding declarations(block) to an Array or Hash. For example:

```
.selector-one { /* This selector and its declaration will be added */
  .
  .
float: right;
  .
  .
}

#selector-two { /* This selector and its declaration will be added */
  .
  .
margin-left: 20%;
  .
  .
}
```

I'm trying to write it using the scan method, This way:

```
content.scan(/.*?\{.*?(right|left).*?\}/)
```

Or

```
content.scan(/[^}]\{[^}](right|left)[^}]\}/)
```

But non of them work.

**I should mention that:**

- It dosn't matter if the name of the selector contains the word left or right, We just need to check the blocks.
- The name of the selectors may start with anything other than `{` or `}`
- Selectors can be grouped, So we could have something like this:

.

```
h1, h2, p {
    text-align: right;
    color: red;
}
```

Comment: I'm so sorry if my question wasn't clear because I didn't consider other ways to write this program. I updated my question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to all the people answered to my question. Unfortunately non of them solve the problem. Here is how I implemented it:

```
input.scan(/[^{}]*\{[^}]*?(?:\Wright\W|\Wleft\W)[^}]*\}/)
```

The key was that the parentheses in scan method make a capture group. So we need to turn it into a non-capturing group, using `?:`

Answer (score 0):

I don't know ruby but the regexp should be :

```
[{]([^}]*(right|left)[^}]*)[}]
```

With ungreedy,insensitive and global flags

Answer (score 0):

Based on your sample, and if they aren't nested.

```
 #  \.(selector-[^{}]*?)\s*\{([^{}]*:[ ]*(?:right|left)[ ]*;[^{}]*)\}

 \.
 ( selector- [^{}]*? )       # (1), Selector
 \s* 
 \{
 (                           # (2 start), Block
      [^{}]* 
      : [ ]* 
      (?: right | left )
      [ ]* ;
      [^{}]* 
 )                           # (2 end)
 \}
```

Output:

```
 **  Grp 0 -  ( pos 0 , len 105 ) 
.selector-one { /* This block will be added to the array */
    .
    .
float: right;
    .
    .
}  
 **  Grp 1 -  ( pos 1 , len 12 ) 
selector-one  
 **  Grp 2 -  ( pos 15 , len 89 ) 
 /* This block will be added to the array */
    .
    .
float: right;
    .
    .

----------------------

 **  Grp 0 -  ( pos 196 , len 106 ) 
.selector-three { /* This block will be added to the array */
    .
    .
float: left;
    .
    .
}  
 **  Grp 1 -  ( pos 197 , len 14 ) 
selector-three  
 **  Grp 2 -  ( pos 213 , len 88 ) 
 /* This block will be added to the array */
    .
    .
float: left;
    .
    .
```

Answer (score 0):

Ruby's [`slice_before`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.4/Enumerable.html#method-i-slice_before) is handy for this:

```
blocks = DATA.each_line
             .slice_before(/^\./)
             .map(&:join)
             .select{ |block| block[/\b(?:left|right)\b/] } 
blocks 
# => [".selector-one { /* This block will be added to the array */\n    .\n    .\nfloat: right;\n    .\n    .\n}\n\n",
#     ".selector-three { /* This block will be added to the array */\n    .\n    .\nfloat: left;\n    .\n    .\n}\n"]


__END__
.selector-one { /* This block will be added to the array */
    .
    .
float: right;
    .
    .
}

.selector-two { /* This block wont be added to the array */
    .
    .
    .
}

.selector-three { /* This block will be added to the array */
    .
    .
float: left;
    .
    .
}
```

- [`each_line`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.4/IO.html#method-i-each_line) iterates over the lines in the file.
- [`slice_before`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.4/Enumerable.html#method-i-slice_before) looks through the resulting array, and creates sub-arrays when the regular expression `/^\./` matches a line that starts with `.`.
- `map(&:join)` converts the contents of each sub-array back into a text string.
- `select` looks inside each string and if `/\b(?:left|right)\b/` matches the word "left" or "right", then the string is passed on.

It's important to use a pattern like `/\b(?:left|right)\b/`, because the string being searched for could be embedded in a longer string like 'leftover' or 'bright' and you don't want to get a false-positive.

You might not have seen [`__END__` and `DATA`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.4/Object.html) before, but they're handy for test code like this. `__END__` marks the end of the script, and anything after it can be treated as a pseudo data file, which is accessible via `DATA`. So consider the code to be reading from a file.

Answer (score 0):

You could also use a CSS parser like [Crass](https://github.com/rgrove/crass/) and scan the [parse tree](https://github.com/rgrove/crass/#examples).

Spitballing code now...

```
tree = Crass.parse(css)
nodes_with_right_or_left = tree.select do |node|
  node[:children] and node[:children].detect do |child|
    child[:value] == "right" or child[:value] == "left"
  end
end
```

YMMV :-)